# Non standard exercise with a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

We have the following system of differential equations:

$\begin{cases}
   \frac{dx}{dt} = -x+xy\\
   \frac{dy}{dt} = -2y-x^2 
\end{cases}$

We're asked to prove that the maximal solutions are defined on all $\mathbb{R}$ and that 
$$ \lim_{t \to \infty}{(x(t),y(t))} = 0. $$

We're also asked to prove that if $(x(0),y(0)) \neq (0,0)$ than

$$ (x(t),y(t)) \neq (0,0) \ \ \forall t \in \mathbb{R} $$

I've done something like this before, but i can't figure out how to solve this one. Thanks in advance for every hint\solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the Lyapunov function $V=x^2+y^2$ (that works for almost all textbook examples). Then
$$
\dot V=\frac{d}{dt}V(x(t),y(t))=2(-x^2-2y^2)
$$
so that
$$
-4V\le \dot V \le -2V\implies V_0e^{-3t-|t|}\le V(t)\le V_0e^{-3t+|t|}.
$$
From these inequalities all the claims can be concluded.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Is there some other way to do that, for example using the fact that the solution must "escape" from every compact contained in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: I'm not sure where you want to go with this argument. The inequalities show that if the compact in time-space is cylindrical and you make the space-ball large enough, then any solution must leave this compact only in the time-sides. Thus any local solution is infinitely extensible.